# Capacitance absurd equation in textbook help

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, capacitance

In a textbook I have this equation:

> $$I_0 = \frac{q_0}{RC} = \frac{V_0}{R}$$

I tried calculating this, can someone please explain this?

$R$ is resistance, $C$ is capacitance, and $I_0$ and $q_0$ both mean maximum initial current and charge when a capacitance is being discharged through another resistor. $V_0$ is also the initial maximum as the capacitor is connected to the other resistor

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: The meaning of the equation is probably provided by the context in which it is given in the textbook. What does the textbook have to say about the equation?

Answer (score 3):

The charge held on a capacitor, and the voltage across it are related by $q = C V$. By Ohm's law the voltage across the resistor is related to the current passing through it by $V = I R$.

In particular, at $t=0$: $q_0 = C V_0$ and $V_0 = I_0 R$. If you combine these results to eliminate $V_0$ then you obtain that $q_0 = (C R) I_0$ which is the first equation you have (and the second equation is simply Ohm's law).

You can also show this more fully by calculating the time dependent voltage across the capacitor (it drops exponentially with time), and working out the time-dependence of the charge and current from this, and then setting $t=0$.